# Create AWS secrets using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-secrets-manager

I'm playing with ansible playbooks and I wonder if anyone can advise on how to proceed. I would like to create AWS secrets but I a little bit confused.

I don't want to put the password in the playbook and I don't want to store in an environment variable.

Would it be possibel to create them using ansible playbook? And is it possible to put a random password that would be visible only if we access the secret manager?

I know how to retrieve them using the [lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_secret_lookup.html).

Any advise is welcome

Comment: Do you want to invoke the ansible script from the EC2 or Lambda? I'd try to set an IAM role to the instance to allow the SecretManager services (I'm not sure it will work with Ansible, but based on the used libraries it should)

Answer (score 0):

`ansible-vault` was designed for storing encrypted secrets.  Either in an encrypted file, or inline (an encrypted block within a plaintext document).

Check on docs.ansible.com for more information.  And search for ansible vault tutorials as well.

I use them for credentials (sudoers password) so that I don't have to risk locking my account when I mistype my password and ansible tries it 300 times.  (Yay automation!)

Edit:  For the random password part, you can use a utility like pwgen.  Then I'd put it in a vault or AWS secrets manager.

Comment: Ansible Vault is one thing... But, I would like to have them stored in AWS to be able to retrieve them and use them for example when provisioning an RDS instance.

Comment: @amir that you should specify in the question too, As well what do you mean by `password that would be visible only if we access the secret manager?`

Comment: @amir you can put the encrypted secret anywhere you like, in a text file or wherever.  As for generating random passwords, pwgen is useful...And you can call commands (cmd:) or scripts (shell:) from within ansible.